# I want to have the page list in a dropdown field for my content type

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I created a content type TestType.

I would like to have a field type Link.
This type will list all my current page in a dropdown.

Is there any existing module for that?

**Update** 


I have a content type Called

SlidesShow. For each page (Home, Services, Menu =>SubMenu (Principal, dessert etc..)
the SlideShow content is different. 
In this case When the customer enter a new SlideShow Content in the Content manager, I want him to specify witch page this slideshow content will be apply throught a dropdown list.

Note : If I add a new page, the dropdown list should be automaticaly updated.

FieldType : Body 
 FieldType : Image 
 FieldType : PAGE LIST (This is what I'm looking for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "This type will list all my current page in a dropdown"? If you want to have a field with a dropdown with options as all the node pages, you might be better putting a node reference field there.

Comment: Hi Neo, I'm not sure to understand what you mean about putting a node reference fields. My problem here, Is I need to create a slideshow with different content base on the page you are looking at. In the content Manager, when I add a picture to my slideshow content type, I would like to specify for witch page this content will be apply. This is the reason why I would need a dropdown list with all my current page

Answer (score 1):

Well now i think i get your use case. Here is what you need to do:

1. in the slideshow content type create a textfield for specifying the page. Here is one thing to consider. If you are sure the pages in which you will use the slideshow will be specifically node pages you add a node reference field instead of textfield.
2. While creating the view, use a contextual filter on the field and specify a default value to get the current page URL. You can use views php module to add a php filter instead of contextual filter and pull in $_GET['q'] of the page.

I hope this helps. please let me know if you have other queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extra information. That was exacly what I needed :)